# BootStrap Input type text not appearing in modal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have a basic modal that has 3 fields. Name, email, and message. The email and message appear perfectly. The name input field doesn't appear. It only appears when Name label is clicked. May I ask why it does this and how can I override it so it displays normal like email and message.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="contact" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <form class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4>Contact Tech Site</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="contact-name" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Name:</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">

              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact-name" placeholder="Full Name">

            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">

            <label for="contact-email" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email:</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">

              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="contact-email" placeholder="you@example.com">

            </div>

          </div>

          <div class="form-group">

            <label for="contact-msg" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Message:</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">

              <textarea class="form-control" rows="8"></textarea>

            </div>

          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <a class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Send</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I wasn't able to replicate this in codepen. How it appears http://snag.gy/7Zd3f.jpg

Comment: The name input field does appear in the screenshot you shared - misaligned though.

Comment: It looks fine for me, see [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/5f37rhtr/). There must be something else interfering, any other CSS that matches `#contact-name`?

Comment: Hi @AviDubey It only appears if I click name label. Chrki, I tried changing to another id name, that didn't work as well.

Comment: Cabn you show your other CSS, obvious this aint a bootstrap issue but an CSS issue that conflicts with bootstrap

Comment: @Master I would also guess it is a CSS issue. Your form code worked fine when I tested.

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me, try taking out "fade" from first line.